# webbrowser imports really slow

Tags: python-3.x, python-webbrowser

Importing `webbrowser` takes 30+ seconds to load, which really slows down the starting up of my program. I've tried setting my default browser to IE and Chrome, but still yielded the same result. Tried it in other machines too.

I'm running Python 3.6.4 (Windows 7 x64) with a fairly fast internet connection. I'm fairly new in python programming as well.

My questions will be:

1. What causes this slowdown? I'm watching youtube videos importing `webbrowser`, they seem to import it instantaneously. What can I do about it?
2. I've tried "cheating" my way around this desperately by putting the import in a function of a button so that it would not affect the startup of the program (didn't work. kind of stupid now I think about it. still took 30+ seconds to startup)
3. Another desperate measure I'm planning to do is put the import into a multi thread so it could import at the background while starting up the program. I haven't done multi threading yet, so I still need to learn this. Would this work though?

I don't know what other information I could share regarding this since I'm really lost here. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Edit: I made a simple py to time the execution of the code.

```
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()
import webbrowser
stop = timeit.default_timer()

print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

How are you so sure that slowdown is due to "import". This could be due to slower loading in your Chrome browser, try clearing the cache of Chrome browser. Did your Chrome browser is upto the mark as speed is considered ? also please show me the code.

Comment: Tried to clear cache. Still takes around 30secs to import. I've added a test module on my original post.

Comment: I ran your test module and it took less than a second. Maybe reinstalling the chrome browser might work !